# Perl: Import text, containing ÅÄÖ, from file

Tags: perl, file, encoding, io

What i'm ultimately trying to achieve here is translating all lowercase characters in a file into uppercase and write them to the terminal.

```
use utf8;
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";

$text = "ABCÅÄÖ\n";

$text =~ tr/A-Ö/a-ö/;
print $text;
```

Outputs:

`abcåäö`

As expected.

But when i try to import the same text from a file it gets all crazy.

```
use utf8;
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";

open FILE, $filename or die "An error occurred while reading the file: $!";
$text = join '', <FILE>;
close FILE or die "An error occurred while closing the file: $!";

$text =~ tr/A-Ö/a-ö/;
print $text;
```

Outputs

`ABCÃÃÃ`

I'm assuming the imported text is not properly encoded. Anyone know how to encode text while importing it?

Thanks in advance.

Jack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't tell Perl to decode the file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use utf8;                             # Source code is UTF-8.
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';  # Terminal and files are UTF-8.

my $qfn = ...;

open(my $fh, '<', $qfn)
   or die("Can't open file $qfn: $!\n");

my $text = do { local $/; <$fh> };
print(lc($text));
```

Comment: Well, it's unsafe to rely on `$text =~ tr/A-Ö/a-ö/`. Either use `lc($text)` or `$text =~ s/([A-ZÅÄÖ])/\L$1/g`. I made a number of other improvements (lexicals instead of globals, 3-arg open, incl file name in error message, ...)

Answer (score 1):

Just tell Perl what encoding the file is in:

```
open FILE, '<:utf8', $filename or die $!;
```

Or, if you want to check the encoding, use

```
open FILE, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename or die $!;
```

Comment: Odd... When I use this method the import is fine (IE i can print the text fine), but when translate it, the Å Ä and Ö are still scrambled.

Comment: @JackPettersson: Try `lc` rather than `tr`.